# Exclude sites from web search

Tags: search, search-engine

Is it possible to exclude certain sites from a web search so they don't appear in the search results? Some search engines have a feature called safe search, but that doesn't look configurable (at least not in DuckDuckGo or Google).

I'm mainly using DuckDuckGo in Firefox, but I'd consider switching to a different search engine (or even a different browser) if this is possible.

A (hypothetical of course) example: Some might think that answers.microsoft.com is an utterly useless site that never gives the answers you are looking for. How to never show that site ever?

Comment: [How do I exclude/block specific web sites from search results? - Google Search Community](https://support.google.com/websearch/thread/2601677/how-do-i-exclude-block-specific-web-sites-from-search-results?hl=en)

Comment: [How to Block a Website in Google Chrome: 6 Helpful Methods](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-block-a-website-on-chrome)

Comment: Not strictly what you asked, but I suppose you know you can exclude words from browser search results by prefixing them with a minus sign. So "operating system -Microsoft" *should* return all results that contain "operating system" but don't contain the word "Microsoft"